# uiautomatorviewer Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file

Tags: uiautomatorviewer

I can capture one screen of a app, and other screen is well.

the gui says: Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file.
Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file.

and the terminal's log is:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/var/folders/vs/30nqjbc16kd21g3hc_5h7vg40000gn/T/uiautomatorviewer_1759068495088939262/dump_421507564099289174.uix; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1019)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:328)
    at com.android.uiautomator.tree.UiHierarchyXmlLoader.parseXml(UiHierarchyXmlLoader.java:130)
    at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorModel.<init>(UiAutomatorModel.java:51)
    at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorHelper.takeSnapshot(UiAutomatorHelper.java:155)
    at com.android.uiautomator.actions.ScreenshotAction$1.run(ScreenshotAction.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
null rootnode after parsing.
```

Update:
I change a phone, now every thing is ok..

Comment: Did you figure what the problem was?

Comment: @DineshVG No, I didn't

Comment: On my site a simple reboot made it work again, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247031/uiautomatorviewer-location-of-file-error-obtaining-ui-hierachy/53248070#53248070

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your using Android 7.1.1 or higher  you have to configure certain things in developer option in your mobile

`1. Turn on USB DEBUGGING
 2.  Enable view attribute inspection 
 3.  Select the debug app option and choose com.github.uiautomator`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've found temporal workaround. The thing is that there are 2 different APIs for UiAutomator. One is old, deprecated and used by UiAutomatorViewer, while second is new one and commonly used by tests (which access things like UiObject2). From what I've seen this problem is reproducible only with deprecated API (so only when you use UiAutomatorViewer). My workaround may seem strange but for me it works 100% time, simply when you're installing your app (e.g. green button in Android Studio) you need to drag and drop your emulator / device and just move something. E.g. keep moving some scroll area or whatever and then when your app shows up you should now be able to use UiAutomatorViewer without this issue.

Yes ... I know this is super weird and feels completely unrelated but I've tested it multiple times and when I do drag and drop while installing my app the UiAutomatorViewer just works fine but when I'm not doing that I'm getting exactly same error. As to the tests it didn't matter if I do that or not, they were always working fine (but as I've mentioned they use newer API).